# Import RDP file into Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Manager 2.7

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, import

I have been using Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Manager 2.7 for a while now and enjoy using it a lot. What I have noticed is that there doesn't seem to be a way to import the connection settings from a standard RDP file into Remote Desktop Connection Manager.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? I have 100s of individual RDP files that I am given every month and I rather not have to individually type all the settings one by one.

I already know that there is an Import Setting under "Edit > Import Server" but this option only allows you to import the server names from a text file, but none of the settings for the server.

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: I'm curious if you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, and the PowerShell suggestion below did not work either. This would be something that would have to be coded, and even then the most you can do is to import the connection information from the RDP file, which would not include any saved credentials, which means you would have to still manually enter each credential one by one so not a good option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware that you can import separate .rdp files however as .rdp files are readable as text files. A simple powershell script should do the job:

```
$Path = "C:\Import into RDCMan"
$Text = "full address:s:"
$PathArray = @()
$File = ""
$String = ""
$FinalString = ""

Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.rdp" |
    Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} |
    ForEach-Object {
        If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Text) {
            $File = $PathArray += $_.FullName
            $String = Get-Content $File | Where-Object { $_.Contains($Text) }
            $FinalString = $String.substring(15)
    }
}
$FinalString | % {$_} | Out-File "IPs.txt"
```

Just change the $Path variable to the folder which contains all of your .rdp files. Run the Powershell script and it will create an IPs.txt files ready to import into RDCMan.

P.S. You may need to run this before running the script:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only grabs the Server Name. I am looking to import all the settings, such as "screen mode", "desktop width", "gateway host name", etc.

Answer (score -1):

Right click -> Open With -> Remote Desktop
This will then open the Remote Desktop Connection App and allow you to connect!

Comment: That is not what the question was. Please read my original question again.